# Is it feasible to view what webpages a person uses from their wi-fi, without access?

Tags: cryptography, privacy

[BBC uses detection vans to detect license fee dodgers](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/08/05/bbc-to-deploy-detection-vans-to-snoop-on-internet-users/)

Is what is described in the article feasible, assuming the user has properly set up their wi-fi with a secure password?

In addition even if it is feasible to do so, in dense areas is it feasible to match a wi-fi to an individual? I'd presume an attempt at triangulation could be possible, but with the varying number and density of people's walls in a built up area, I can't see it being possible to reliably pinpoint a wifi signal to an individual house, barring getting architectural plans for all houses in the area and simulating signal propagation ( which clearly is not a scaleable idea ).

In addition, assuming that both of these things are feasible, is it legal?

Comment: As far as legality is concerned, it's no different than somebody standing outside hearing you scream at the TV: you are voluntarily emitting signals detectable outside.

Comment: That isn't a good analogy, and it is definitely different than that. When I send my bank details across the internet to make a payment, I am voluntarily emitting signals detectable outside. It is however not legal to intercept those signals and unencrypt them.

Comment: I would strongly advise thinking about it as "overhearing," not "intercepting;" intercepting is an inaccurate word. And the point of the encryption is to prevent an overhearer from overhearing the *actual* conversation. It is still no different from you talking to your friend in the mall in code and having somebody else overhear you and try to figure out what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only passively viewing traffic passing over an encrypted network, as the BBC are going to do, then it's not possible to view the exact web pages that the user is viewing, but some information is still leaked, because the pattern of traffic for streaming video is very distinctive compared to, for example, regular web browsing. As iPlayer was created by the BBC, rather than just reusing some web player software, it is possible that the pattern of traffic (specifically the size and frequency of the bursts of traffic) when viewing iPlayer is unique, and that is what the linked article suggests is what the BBC will be doing. The article also says

> the BBC could manipulate the packets that the iPlayer sends out to see if they match those on a network.

Though at that point, they could just ask the ISP for the address and name associated with the IP address that they are targeting, without needing to send out surveillance vans (though I'm not quite sure why that isn't their plan in the first place...).

If the network is not protected with a password, the traffic is sent in plain text, so, provided that you're not using a VPN, they would be able to see the traffic between you and the iPlayer servers, including the full URLs and the content that is returned.

In flats, it would be more difficult to match a wifi network to an individual, but for houses you can simply see what network is strongest near the house, and check that it gets weaker as you move away. It's not foolproof, but it is a good start. The article also mentions directional antennae,  which would make it even easier.

Regarding the legality, the article says

> Packet sniffing is generally illegal on somebody else’s network but the Regulation of Investigatory Powers Act gives certain bodies permission to monitor internet communications. The BBC has been given authority under the Act to watch home Wi-Fi connections.

So it would be illegal for you to try this, but not for the BBC.

Comment: However, the idea of watching Wi-Fi, is to prevent non-licensee's from using licensee's Wi-Fi-networks. Thats why they will need to use survelliance vans in addition to tracking down which IPs that accesses iPlayer. HOWEVER, the regulation gives them also right to require TV license for any other live stream, so even waching PewDiePie on live Twitch will require a TV license. The difference is that downloading or watching onDemand on BBC iPlayer requires a license, even if its not a live stream, while Twitch would be watchable provided you are not watching live.

Comment: Also, I don't believe packet sniffing on Wifi is illegal as long as you only passively sniff, as the normal working of a Wifi network card is to receive everything, but software on computer toss away anything that is not destined for the client in question, thus you only read what you already receive. Which would be compared with running a packet sniffer on a hubbed network that you are allowed to connect to (and not switched network). However, this detection technique may require BBC to send packets, for example deauth packets or such things and thus would count as "sniffing".

Comment: and thats why they have gained authority in case. Eg, RIPA permission can be gained even for an act that its not illegal, just "in case".